# Camel servlet endpoint - no xml implementation

Tags: servlets, spring-boot, apache-camel

Is there anywhere a working (runnable) example of implementation of Camel servlet endpoint with "no-xml" approach? Working unit test with http-client wold also be great. To me, the set up seems too "complicated" being not familiar with servlet configurations. Examples I can find use mostly XML-only approach.

I'm using Camel on top of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its covered in the Camel in Action 2nd edition book, where there is a camel-servlet example in the microservices chapter 7.
https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition

The example comes as part of a bigger use-case but its the rating service: https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter7/prototype/rating